# how to use pickle in python to store parsed variables on the disk.

Tags: python

I have a file called co2a0000364.rd.002

```
enter code here

  #   co2a0000364.rd

  #   120 trials, 64 chans, 416 samples 368 post_stim samples

  #   3.906000 msecs uV
```

#   S1 obj , trial 0
  #   FP1 chan 0
  0 FP1 0 -8.921
  0 FP1 1 -8.433

I want to use library “pickle” to store parsed variables on the disk.

```
  >>>   import pickle

  >>>   import pprint

  >>>   data= open("C:\\Users\\sonia\co2a0000364.rd.002")

  >>>   pprint.pprint(data)
<_io.TextIOWrapper name='C:\\Users\\sonia\\co2a0000364.rd.002' mode='r'    encoding='cp1252'>
  >>>   data_string = pickle.dumps(data)
   Traceback (most recent call last):
   File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
   TypeError: cannot serialize '_io.TextIOWrapper' object
```

Comment: `data` is a file handle, not the file contents. what you want is `data.read()` which will return the entire contents of the file. but since your file is just plain text, pickling it wont achieve much

Comment: data.read("C:\\Users\\sonia\co2a0000364.rd.002")
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: integer argument expected, got 'str'
>>>

Comment: no no no. after this line: `data= open("C:\\Users\\sonia\co2a0000364.rd.002")` do something like: `file_contents = data.read()`

Comment: How I use pickle in these please?

Comment: All you are doing is storing a pickled version of a python string instead of the original file text. How are you using these pickle files where it would not be equally if not more convenient to read the original files contents via open(file).read()?

Answer (score 0):

you are trying to pickle a file handle, not the file contents. try the following changes to your code:

```
import pickle
import pprint
data= open("C:\\Users\\sonia\co2a0000364.rd.002")
file_contents = data.read()
pprint.pprint(file_contents)
data_string = pickle.dumps(file_contents)
```

`file_contents` will hold the contents of your file
`data_string` will hold a pickled version of it